# How to disable the selection of dropdownlist box items after page loaded?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, drop-down-menu

Based on the first input of dropdownlist box, second dropdownlist box should enable for selection

Have used below javascript for disabling the selection of item.

```
function close_other_box(box){
    if(box.id="dropdown1" && box.selectedIndex<2){
        document.getElementById('dropdown2').value="Select"
        document.getElementById('dropdown2').disabled=true
    } else {
        document.getElementById('dropdown2').disabled=false
    }
}
```

When I run the page "dropdown2" is not geting disable , after i made selection on first "dropdown1" only
dropdown2 geting disable.....

What I need is,

when page is loaded I need to disable the dropdown2...

Comment: "If" condition is missing "==".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `window.onload`

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById('dropdown2').disabled=true;
}
```

Here's [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hy5Dz/)

Answer (score 1):

You can Call the Disable Function on Onload event of Body as follow...

```
 <script>
    function disablesecondDropDown(){
    document.getElementById('dropdown2').value="Select";
    document.getElementById('dropdown2').disabled=true;
    }
    </script>
```

**In Html:-**

```
<body onload="disablesecondDropDown()">
```